# Meteor Cordova iOS - Javascript logs not showing in XCode console

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, logging, meteor

I am currently developing a Cordova Plugin for Objective-C that is used in a Meteor project.

For debugging purpose, I like to have some logs shown in the console. I have no problem logging text from Objective-C with the `NSLog()` method, but I am not able to log from Javascript with the `console.log()` method.

In approx. 20 tries (most of the time without changing any code), I *did* see Javascript logs 2 times in my console. Both times, there was a javascript error showing before my logs.

Here are the errors I got the times my logs were showing :

**First time**

```
Exception in setTimeout callback: t@http://meteor.local/d716df1e7be6951129825f5c7a5659ddb8e2eb39.js:176:1000
attach@http://meteor.local/d716df1e7be6951129825f5c7a5659ddb8e2eb39.js:176:7474
http://meteor.local/d716df1e7be6951129825f5c7a5659ddb8e2eb39.js:176:7676
o@http://meteor.local/d716df1e7be6951129825f5c7a5659ddb8e2eb39.js:3:4970
withValue@http://meteor.local/d716df1e7be6951129825f5c7a5659ddb8e2eb39.js:3:12731
http://meteor.local/d716df1e7be6951129825f5c7a5659ddb8e2eb39.js:196:3493
http://meteor.local/d716df1e7be6951129825f5c7a5659ddb8e2eb39.js:3:19555
http://meteor.local/d716df1e7be6951129825f5c7a5659ddb8e2eb39.js:196:863
w@http://meteor.local/d716df1e7be6951129825f5c7a5659ddb8e2eb39.js:196:2993
```

**Second time**

```
Uncaught Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Event.prototype.stopImmediatePropagation'):176:http://meteor.local/d716df1e7be6951129825f5c7a5659ddb8e2eb39.js
```

But all the other times, I get no error and no logs. I compared the whole log files of the times it worked and the times it didn't, and those 2 errors are the only difference.

Does anyone have an idea of why most of the time I cannot see my Javascript logs?